# localStorage variable becomes Undefined

Tags: php, html, jquery

So I have a table that is populated by php from mysql database, in my table I have an editable cell using **contenteditable** attribute. What I'm trying to achieve is that when focused on the cell the check button for the row should appear and after focusing out the button will disappear and the data in the will return to the original value since it is not save in the database unless the check button will be clicked. so far my code do as expected however after clicking the cells in the column for several times it displays undefined in the cell. Can someone help me? is there any other way to do this?
here's my html code:

```
<?php session_start(); 
include '../assets/back-end-includes/DB-connection.php';
$selectsizeQuery="SELECT * 
                  FROM `sizetable` ";
$selectsizeResult=filtertable($selectsizeQuery);
?>
<div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table table-dark table-hover table-sm" id="dataTable">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Size</th>
                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody  id="tableBody">
                        <?php 
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($selectsizeResult)){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td contenteditable class="tableCell">
                            <input type="text" class="idInput" value="<?php echo $row['sizeID']; ?>" hidden>
                            <strong class="cellData"><?php echo $row['sizeName']; ?></strong>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm sizeEditBtn" name="productEditBtn[]">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                              </button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm sizeDeleteBtn" name="productDeleteBtn[]" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteProductModal">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                              </button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and this is how my jquery script look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dataTable tbody td .sizeEditBtn").hide();
$("#dataTable tbody .tableCell").focus(function() {
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  var originalValue = currentRow.find(".cellData").html();
  localStorage.setItem('originalValue', originalValue);
  currentRow.find(".sizeEditBtn").show();
});
$("#dataTable tbody .tableCell").focusout(function() {
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  currentRow.find(".sizeEditBtn").hide();
  var originalValue = localStorage.getItem('originalValue');
  $(this).html(originalValue);
  localStorage.clear();
});
</script>
```

any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this sentence

```
var originalValue = currentRow.find(".cellData").html();
```

use

```
var originalValue = $(this).html();
```